# maven unable to differentiate between two similar classes in different jars

Tags: java, jar, maven-3

i am using Maven 3 and trying to build a jar.Now there is a class which is present in two different  dependent jars. Though the methods in the interface is different but maven is trying to get the method defined in the class in different jar . So how to ensure that the class is picked from another jar?
E.g the required class is xyz.class and is present in two differnet jars as:
jar1: com/mycompany/xyz.class
and jar2: com/mycompany/xyz.class 
The xyz.class in jar1 is what maven is picking up i suppose but i want the one in jar2
Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? Maven builds your jar (say MyJar), in your jar  there is a class (say MyClass) that makes use of xyz.class that is defined in jar1, and in jar2. You've added dependencies to both of these jar via <dependency> tag in your pom.xml. Now what do you mean by saying that maven picks up xyz.class from jar1? After all maven just builds your own jar(MyJar.jar) that shouldn't contain xyz.class at all. All it should have is your MyClass.class as a compiled binary (and other classes from defined for this Jar. During runtime some xyz.class should be available. Thats it

Comment: actually maven is unable to build MyJar and shows build failure that it is unable to find a method ..This method is present in xyz.class of jar2 instead of xyz.class in jar1

Comment: Unless you clarify what is really happening, I thing what you are trying to is ideally wrong.

Comment: I think, maven will chose the class xyz that comes first in your classpath, and you can't really fiddle with this during compile time. In general your situation shouldn't happen at all, unless you're trying to work with the same jar of different versions).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Java compilation problem than Maven. Check out the answers for:
[how to load same class from different jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854056/how-to-load-same-class-from-different-jars)

You'll need to define your custom class loader for this kind of situation.