# Can I choose which one to use if two files generated from two artifacts share name/pacakge but contain different content?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, dependency-management

As the title mentioned, is there a way in Maven to select which one to use if two files share the name/package but contain different content. I could not simply exclude one artifact because each of them carries some information used by other files. And it is also not feasible to refactor two artifact due to some restrictions and limitations of our project. I am just wondering if it is possible to prioritize one of them. Thanks.

P.S. I am using maven 3

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is already some discussion about this existing on this forum
[how to load same class from different jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854056/how-to-load-same-class-from-different-jars)